# Dar formato a un COUNT para que tenga tres cifras empezando desde 000

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un `COUNT` de mis registros mensuales para rellenar el número de factura, y mi formato es de tres números finales, empezando por `001`, a mí normalmente me sale solo `1`. El resto del número de factura esta controlado, al final es `AA-MM-XXX` dos finales del año, mes, y tres números empezando por `001`, y cada mes se reinician.

```sql
SET @id=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numero);
insert INTO numero (id, fecha) VALUES (null, (concat(date_format(now(),"%y-%m-"),(@id+1))));
```

Este código me crea una entrada en mi tabla, de la forma que yo busco, `YY-MM`, pero yo busco un número de tres cifras `XXX` en cambio, me sale una cifra `X`.

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta? Cuál es el código asociado a la pregunta? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: La función que necesitas es `LPAD(COUNT(*),3,'0')`. Otra cosa ya sería si es mejor hacer un `SET` como haces o si se puede hacer la consulta en la misma sentencia del `INSERT`. Pero a lo que preguntas... la función de rellenar con ceros, podría ser esa.

Comment: muchiiiisimas gracias

Comment: @VFG añádelo respuesta para que se resuelva y enhorabuena por ese detalle tan bueno, si eso lo pongo yo en tu lugar :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javier, la función que necesitas es

```
LPAD(COUNT(*),3,'0')
```

Otra cosa ya sería si es mejor hacer un `SET` como haces o si se puede hacer la consulta en la misma sentencia del `INSERT`. Pero a lo que preguntas... la función de rellenar con ceros, podría ser esa.

Comment: +1 muy buena respuesta, ahora solo falta que se la pueda aplicar porques lo estoy intentado y no hay manera

Comment: No se puede realizar un ***insert o update*** con esta función ya que ***MySQL*** omite por defecto los 0 de la izquierda, de tal modo que aunque se modifique mysql los omite...

Comment: DIscutamos este problema en la [sala de mysql](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136425/stack-overflow-en-espanol-mysql)

Comment: Javier G. Raya, sí se podría hacer el **INSERT**. Por ejemplo con `INSERT INTO numero (id,fecha) SELECT NULL, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%y-%m-"),LPAD(COUNT(*),3,'0')) FROM numero`  Si quiere sumar uno más del contador real, sería añadir `+1`al `COUNT(*)` pero eso ya depende de necesidades reales de Javier Monleón. El tema es que lo que parece una fecha, no lo es. Ha de ser un STRING (me imagino que Javier Monleón lo tiene así). Le llama "Fecha" pero ha de ser un STRING porque si no no tiene sentido que rellene con ceros hasta 3 caracteres

Comment: Yo es que los numerico no lo pongo como string

Comment: Pues sí, Javier... Yo tampoco. Y en general cuando nombro `Fecha` a un campo es porque es una fecha. Pero me imagino que lo quiere a modo de registro de algo marcando año y mes en que lo hacía. Pero en fin... eso ya es mucho adivinar. La clave es eso de los 3 dígitos... eso es lo que hace presumir que en realidad no es un dato de fecha, porque además lo mezcla con un contador (no de días)

Comment: Si eso metete en [la sala de MySQL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136425/stack-overflow-en-espanol-mysql) y lo podemos hablar mysql

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver ese problema necesita como bien te comenta el usuario ***VFG*** es :

```
LPAD(COUNT(*),3,'0')
```

Con eso podrás cambiar el formato.

***Por ejemplo :***

| Count |
| --- |
| 003 |

Si aplicamos esto a la tabla empleados nos devolverá el numero de empleados que hay en esa tabla.

```
SELECT LPAD(COUNT(*),3,'0') FROM empleados;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/304)

Answer (score 1):

En principio, como bien dicen pongo fecha, pero sí es un string, solo que la columna de la base de datos lo nombré *fecha*.
Y sí, también tiene razón, que no funciona la respuesta al 100%: sigue sin ponerme ceros al principio, así que busqué en hilos en inglés y di con la respuesta correcta. Todavía no acabo de entender cómo funciona, pero después de horas y muchos fallos me funcionó. Eso sí: no soy capaz de hacerlo funcionar sin el `SET`.

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
SET @id=(SELECT LPAD(COUNT(*),3,'0') FROM numero);
insert INTO numero (id, fecha) VALUES (null, (concat(date_format(now(),"%y-%m-"),(lpad((@id+1), 3, '0')))));
```

Como ya podrán comprobar mi tabla se llama *numero*, y consta de id autoincrementable, y *fecha* que es el numero(string) que sería el resultante de la funcion SQL.  `YY-MM-XXX`

El [código](/a/535168/) que hizo [el usuario VFG](/users/278458/vfg) también funciona, lo único que no entiendo es un `INSERT` y en vez de poner `VALUES`, pone `SELECT`.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te fue más útil.

Comment: Además, recuerda que el formato de [es.so] es de _preguntas y respuestas_, y las respuestas no se muestran necesariamente en orden cronológico. ¡Evita saludar y agradecer en tu respuesta! En su lugar, si necesitas dar o solicitar aclaraciones, debes dejar comentarios en las respuestas (o editar tu pregunta, si necesitas más detalles). Además, una forma de agradecer es votando a favor de la respuesta que te fue útil (o "las respuestas", si son varias).

Comment: Por último: 1. para que puedas explicar correctamente el funcionamiento del código, investiga todo lo "extraño" que veas en la consulta en la propia documentación de MySQL. 2. Hablando de documentación: [`INSERT SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html). No olvides explicar el funcionamiento del código: recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para ti, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad que lleguen a tener un problema similar. Puede que no todos comprendan lo que hace la consulta.